# Determine daily access in Android

Tags: android

I want to determinate a daily access in Android, I know that can I use SQLite but I want to use something more lightly.

I can determinate the day of the access using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    switch (day) {
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            // Current day is Sunday
            break;
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            // Current day is Monday
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            // etc.
            break;
    }
```

But how can I determine if the user accesses my app for (example) 100 consecutive days.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a library that is specially made for that: Firebase analytics, instead of handling all the logic in your app, you can log events to Firebase directly, the app started event is by default available when you setup the library. You can check more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

It's not a simple task to do, once you have lets say your app started event which is basically `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`, you need to do more including saving the events somewhere, processing the events and sending them by HTTP(s) to a web server. Saving the events again in a database and presenting it in the most elegant way. In my opinion Firebase is the answer you're looking for here.